# Multiple compile errors ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart

Tags: flutter

I think I somehow broke my flutter install.  While doing nothing that I can think of as related to this, I suddenly get numerous compile errors in this file.

`ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart`

There are 34 undefined class errors.  Its like this file lost some references.  How can I repair it?

```
error: Undefined class 'PointerDataPacket'. (undefined_class at [liga] ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart:14)
error: Undefined class 'ByteData'. (undefined_class at [liga] ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart:17)
error: Undefined class 'SemanticsAction'. (undefined_class at [liga] ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart:17)
error: Undefined class 'ByteData'. (undefined_class at [liga] ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart:23)
error: Undefined class 'ByteData'. (undefined_class at [liga] ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart:26)
error: The method 'hashValues' isn't defined for the class 'Locale'. (undefined_method at [liga] ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart:378)
error: Undefined class 'Size'. (undefined_class at [liga] ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart:441)
error: Undefined class 'Size'. (undefined_class at [liga] ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart:442)
error: Undefined name 'Size'. (undefined_identifier at [liga] ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart:442)
error: Undefined class 'Zone'. (undefined_class at [liga] ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart:497)
error: Undefined name 'Zone'. (undefined_identifier at [liga] ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart:500)
error: Undefined class 'Zone'. (undefined_class at [liga] ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart:548)
error: Undefined name 'Zone'. (undefined_identifier at [liga] ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart:551)
error: Undefined class 'Zone'. (undefined_class at [liga] ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart:570)
error: Undefined name 'Zone'. (undefined_identifier at [liga] ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart:573)
error: Undefined class 'Zone'. (undefined_class at [liga] ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart:609)
error: Undefined name 'Zone'. (undefined_identifier at [liga] ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart:612)
error: Undefined class 'Zone'. (undefined_class at [liga] ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart:636)
error: Undefined name 'Zone'. (undefined_identifier at [liga] ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart:639)
error: Undefined class 'Zone'. (undefined_class at [liga] ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart:658)
error: Undefined name 'Zone'. (undefined_identifier at [liga] ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart:661)
error: Undefined class 'Zone'. (undefined_class at [liga] ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart:675)
error: Undefined name 'Zone'. (undefined_identifier at [liga] ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart:678)
error: Undefined class 'Scene'. (undefined_class at [liga] ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart:750)
error: Undefined class 'Zone'. (undefined_class at [liga] ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart:768)
error: Undefined name 'Zone'. (undefined_identifier at [liga] ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart:771)
error: Undefined class 'Zone'. (undefined_class at [liga] ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart:784)
error: Undefined name 'Zone'. (undefined_identifier at [liga] ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart:787)
error: Undefined class 'Zone'. (undefined_class at [liga] ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart:800)
error: Undefined name 'Zone'. (undefined_identifier at [liga] ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart:803)
error: Undefined class 'SemanticsUpdate'. (undefined_class at [liga] ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart:813)
error: Undefined class 'ByteData'. (undefined_class at [liga] ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart:839)
error: Undefined class 'Zone'. (undefined_class at [liga] ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart:859)
error: Undefined name 'Zone'. (undefined_identifier at [liga] ios/.symlinks/flutter/common/flutter_patched_sdk/stub_ui/window.dart:862)
```

Output from flutter doctor - v

```
    • Flutter version 1.2.1 at /Users/darrelldavis/Development/Flutter/flutter
    • Framework revision 8661d8aecd (3 months ago), 2019-02-14 19:19:53 -0800
    • Engine revision 3757390fa4
    • Dart version 2.1.2 (build 2.1.2-dev.0.0 0a7dcf17eb)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/darrelldavis/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 10.2.1, Build version 10E1001
    • ios-deploy 1.9.4
    • CocoaPods version 1.6.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 35.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 183.6270
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.33.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 2.26.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone Xʀ • 346FC64F-6915-41C3-98BF-3C3A86E55AAB • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-2 (simulator)

• No issues found!

Output from flutter analyze

Analyzing liga...                                                      ⣽                                                                                                      

   info • This class (or a class which this class inherits from) is marked as '@immutable', but one or more of its instance fields are not final: MyApp._userModel •
          lib/app.dart:10:7 • must_be_immutable
   info • This class (or a class which this class inherits from) is marked as '@immutable', but one or more of its instance fields are not final: PinEntryPage._pin •
          lib/pages/pin_entry_page.dart:4:7 • must_be_immutable

2 issues found. (ran in 4.0s)
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `flutter doctor -v` and `flutter analyze`

Comment: Added the requested outputs.

Comment: Same problem here. Have you found a solution or workaround?

Comment: No solution.  I opened an issue on the project but it isn't getting much traction since I'm the only one affected.  Add a comment with any additional info you can and maybe it will help.  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31853